# how can I discard the values from the inner join table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL Query.

```
SELECT CON_ID, MAX(COM_DateTime) AS maxDate
FROM
(
    SELECT CON_ID, COM_DateTime
    FROM CON_Conversation
        INNER JOIN COU_ConversationUser AS cu USING (CON_ID)
        INNER JOIN COM_ConversationMessage AS cm USING (CON_ID)
    WHERE cu.USR_ID = 4328 AND cm.USR_ID = 4328 AND cu.COU_Status <> 'deleted'
 ) AS sub
 GROUP BY CON_ID
 ORDER BY maxDate DESC
```

And From the inner join COU_ConversationUser I would like to discard all the ones that have status deleted. Here is a sample of my table.

[image: COU_ConversationUser]

How can I using this same query discard all the fields front his table that have COU_Status equals to deleted? In this case would be only 1. But I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: When you say discard, do you mean filter from the results, or delete from the table?

Comment: yes, get only the results that have status read and unread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND cu.COU_Status <> 'deleted'
```

should work already.  Since it is not working either you are filtering the wrong field, or more likely the deleted result doesn't match the keyword you are filtering on.  Check for spaces in the table and try `not like %deleted%`.  You seem to be on the right track, likely something small tripping you up.  You can also try:

```
and cu.COU_Status in ('read', 'unread')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that field to the inner select statement, and filtering the 'deleted' records.  This should be close to what you need:

```
SELECT CON_ID, MAX(COM_DateTime) AS maxDate
FROM
(
    SELECT CON_ID, COM_DateTime, cu.COU_Status
    FROM CON_Conversation
        INNER JOIN COU_ConversationUser AS cu USING (CON_ID)
        INNER JOIN COM_ConversationMessage AS cm USING (CON_ID)
    WHERE cu.USR_ID = 4328 AND cm.USR_ID = 4328 AND cu.COU_Status <> 'deleted'
 ) AS sub
 WHERE sub.COU_Status <> 'deleted'
 GROUP BY CON_ID
 ORDER BY maxDate DESC
```

Comment: Unknown column 'sub.COU_Status' in 'where clause' :(

Comment: Does the inner select statement execute without errors?